# file system inconsistency- e2fsck exited with signal 7

Tags: linux, filesystems, raid, hard-drive

After my system is rebooted uncleanly, I faced some file system inconsistency on my 4TB software raid 5 partition (/dev/md3). So I tried `fsck -y -f -v /dev/md3` several times.

Unfortunately the `e2fsck exited with signal 7` command showed up every time.
How can I fix this problem? The system refuses starting with this inconsistency.
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, signal 7 is the same thing as [Bus error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5870353/1068283). This typically has one of two causes:

1. You have a hardware problem with your motherboard, RAM or other critical system components. In this particular case, this is the most likely cause. Try moving the array to a known good computer, or at least attempting to isolate any bad hardware such as the motherboard, RAM or CPU.
2. Your filesystem is so corrupt that something within it is causing `fsck` to crash. This is extremely unlikely with such a widely used tool, but is still within the realm of possibility. If you are 100% certain that you are using the drives in a PC with good hardware, [contact the author of fsck](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck.ext4) (follow the Reporting Bugs process at the bottom of the page).

Comment: In case of 2, is it possible to recover some files from these raid hard drives? i need a way to copy some important file from this partition to a external storage.

Comment: Start with 1 first.

Comment: It seems that my problem was with hardware, i dont know what caused this problem, Motherboard or Hard disk, but this problem fixed by unplug and replug all of SATA cables from motherboard and running "e2fsck -f -v /dev/md3" it showes some inconsistency and hopefully it succeeded with fixing them.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a file-system check w/o the automated response?
**-y** is a common reason of repair failing if the error condition
is non-trivial.

Comment: what you meant by automated response?

Comment: without automated response == Without the `-y` option to `fsck` ...

Comment: yeah, i did that, nothing specific happend.

Comment: Check with `dmesg` and `smartctl` if your disk is healthy, it might be dying.... Then use (or, if lucky, make) a backup after changing the disk.

Comment: "mdadm --details" showed that all raid drives are healthy...